# SubGit: Use Git Pull Request Description as SVN Commit Message

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I see the option to define a custom SVN commit message with the configuration option svnCommitMessage using SubGit.

https://subgit.com/documentation/config-options.html
Looking at this documentation, I don's see any ways to define this by pull request, though.  I believe the options to be per individual commit.  I'd ideally like my SVN message to be the pull request message.

Is this possible?  How?

Comment: Just to be clear, I have SubGit setup with the shelves line removed, and the permissions on the synchronized branch in Git only allow changes via pull request.  So I believe I effectively do a squash going from Git to SVN, meaning that every SVN commit maps one to one with a Git pull request.

Comment: Should also add that I'm using the add on for Bit Bucket in case there are nuanced differences.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time SVN Mirror add-on has no possibility to put pull request message into SVN commit message, all the "svnCommitMessage" placeholders are indeed related to individual commits.

Regarding the branch permissions -- note, that despite that "pull request only" permission changes from SVN will be written into the repository directly.

Honestly, I haven't completely understood your idea about squashing: if you are using "squash" merge strategy, then indeed all the commits will be squashed into a single commit and it will be translated to SVN, so only one commit will appear in the destination branch, but that commit message will not be the same as the pull request comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can you think of a creative way to clean up the SVN commit message?  Maybe have Git somehow put the pull request note into ref/notes?  Or maybe somehow grab the last git commit message instead of all of them, then I make sure that one is concise?  I did not mean to indicate I'm actually doing a squash, just that the behavior from git to svn is similar to a squash of git branch to git branch.